# Bind's do Spring com Collections

Tags: java-ee, spring-mvc, collection

Eu não tenho sido capaz de encontrar uma solução sobre como resolver essa questão ainda, depois de pesquisar e pesquisar achei algo de como posso fazer um bind de elementos de meu form a uma collection em um POJO. Mas antes gostaria de explicar a regra de negocio do modulo no qual estou desenvolvendo para ajudar o leitor a se orientar, logo até mesmo me indicar uma outra solução caso for necessario.

Tenho um form no qual dentro dele eu posso cadastrar "passageiros de viagem" e posteriormente popular uma tabela para quando for submetido a collection ser persistida em banco. Abaixo a imagem para facilitar a visualização:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo criei minhas entity de customer no qual irá conter um Set de passageiros:

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_customer")
    private Long idCustomer;

    @Column(name="birth_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_document")
    private Document document;


    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_customerPhone")
    private CustomerPhone customerPhone;


    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_customer")
    private Set<Passenger> passenger = new HashSet<Passenger>();

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_customerAddress")
    private CustomerAddress customerAddress;


    public Customer() {
    }
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**Passenger.java**

```
@Entity
public class Passenger implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_passengers")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="birth_date")
    private String birthDate;

    @Column(name="p_email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="p_first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="p_last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="main_tel")
    private String mainTel;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="family_bond")
    private FamilyBond familyBond;


    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_documentPassenger")
    private DocumentPassenger documentPassenger;


    public Passenger() {
    }
    //Getter and Setter

}
```

**Meu controller:**

```
@Controller
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    public CustomerFacade customerFacade;

    @RequestMapping("/customer")
    public ModelAndView getMenuService(Model model){
        List<Country> countriesList = customerFacade.getCountriesList();    
        model.addAttribute("countriesList", countriesList);

        return new ModelAndView("customer/newCustomer", "customer", new Customer());
    }
```

Bem, agora que o bicho pega! Pois estou querendo realizar o bind da collection com alguns componentes dentro do meu form na view.

Depois de procurar um bocado acabei achando esta abordagem:

```
<f:form id="transition-duration-demo" class="transition-form" modelAttribute="customer" method="post">
   <div class="aling-form col-sm-12 nest text" style="padding-top:25px">
   <c:forEach items="${customer.passenger}" var="passenger" varStatus="status">

   <div class="box02">
      <f:input id="passenger-name" placeholder="Nome do Passageiro" type="text" path="passenger[${status.index}].firstName" class="form-control"/>
   </div>
   <!--Continua-->
</f:form>
```

Bem, os componentes não aparecem na tela, mas creio que se deva ao motivo da minha lista esteja nula!

Alguém pode me ajudar com essa questão será que estou fazendo da forma correta? Será que alguma pessoa ja usou o AutoPopulatingList do Spring e pode me passar algumas informações?

Comment: João, deixa ver se entendi. Você tem uma modal com uma `form`. Ao "submeter" essa `form` você quer que ela alimente uma tabela na página principal. Quando a tabela da página principal é submetida você quer mandar uma collection inteira (com todos os passageiros cadastrados através da `form`) para ser persistida no server side. É isso?

Comment: Então @AnthonyAccioly e quase isso. Na verdade tenho um `form` no qual os elementos do meu modal pertencem a ele. Quando meu usuário inserir os dados no modal alguns campos vão para a tabela na tela principal (isso é apenas para referência caso o usuário queira excluir algum objeto). Logo, quando os dados do meu `form` (incluindo os dados do modal) forem preenchidos eu realizo o submit. Tenho minha `entity` `Customer.java` na qual existe um `Set` de `Passenger.java` (justamente os campos que estão no modal). Mas o problema está sendo realizar o bind com collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, depois da ajuda de uma amigo do fórum GUJ e um pouco de pesquisa cheguei a conclusão que para popular minha lista teria a possibilidade d fazer por dois modos, **AJAX** ou retirando meu modal do meu `form` principal e criando outro `form` invocando um action em meu controller e assim populando um `List`.

Optei por fazer submetendo um form separado, pois não tenho muita intimidade com chamadas AJAX ainda. Abaixo segue a implementação:

×Close
                Cadastrar Novo Passageiro

```
            <div class="aling-form col-sm-12 nest text" style="padding-top:25px">           

                <div class="box01">
                    <select id="familyBond" class="form-control" name="familyBond">
                        <option value="null" label="-- Vinculo do Passageiro --" />
                        <c:forEach items="${listOfBondNames}" var="bond">
                            <option value="">${bond.value}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </div>

                    <div class="box02">
                        <input id="passenger-name" placeholder="Nome do Passageiro" name="firstName" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box01">
                        <input id="passenger-lastName" placeholder="Sobrenome do Passageiro" type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box02">
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <span class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i class="fa fontawesome-envelope-alt"></i></span>
                            <input id="passenger-email" placeholder="E-mail" type="text"  name="email" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box01">
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <span class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i></span>
                            <input id="passenger-phone" placeholder="Telefone Principal" type="text" name="mainTel" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box02">
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <span class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                            <input id="passenger-birth" placeholder="Data de Nascimento" type="text" name="birthDate" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box01">
                        <input id="passenger-rg" placeholder="RG" type="text" name="documentPassenger.rg" class="form-control" style="margin:0px;"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box02">
                        <input id="passenger-cpf" placeholder="CPF" type="text" name="documentPassenger.cpf" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />

                </div>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer clear" style="margin:0px;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Logo ele chama a action:

```
private List<Passenger> passengerList = new ArrayList<Passenger>();

    @RequestMapping(value="/addPassenger", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addPassenger(Passenger passenger, Model model){
        passengerList.add(passenger);

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("service/newService");
        mv.addObject("passengerList", passengerList);
        mv.addObject("customer", new Customer());
        initializeComponents(model);
       return mv;
    }
```

Com essa abordagem tenho meu passengerList populado para quando for submeter meu form principal eu apanes setar a lista no bean.